# CSS Mystery Spacing

Tags: html, css, padding

I have a simple set of HTML to create a list of images ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/RCuLh/2/)):

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="//cloudinary-a.akamaihd.net/forwardfour/image/upload/h_300,w_200,c_pad,e_vibrance:100/pgznasls8cnqg3vlla7t.jpg" />

    <div class="container">
      <h3 class="title">The Landscape of History</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, if you look at the attached link to JSFiddle, you will notice that the image has about 5px of extra space beneath it. Do you have any idea why it is doing this and what I can do to remove that extra space?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is part of the image; the only way to fix that is to crop it.

(Well, you could use `clip: rect()`. But that’s not a very good way to go about things.)

Comment: Interesting... the Chrome inspector is telling me that the picture is 200x300, not 305, like the height of the parent <li> tag.

Comment: @spryno724: That comes from the hidden `<div>`. You can “fix” it with `line-height: 0;`…

Answer (score 0):

Your image has a 5px (ish) of white space along its bottom edge.  Change the `<body>` background to black and you'll see it.

You'll have to crop the source, or use the image as a background image with an explicit height and no overflow.

Or, you could put a 5px border around the other three edges and turn it into part of the design. :)

The problem of course is that other source images (if this is a catalog-type thing) may not have the 5px border, so really the best solution is edit the source, if you can.